# Make the text enclosed in bold tag as bold

Tags: xml, xslt, text

I have the following XML file.

```
<xml>
 <chapter>
  <p>
    <L-1>
      This is a sample text. I want to <E type='bold'>display this text in bold.<E> This is good.
    </L-1>
  </p>
  <figure>
  </figure>
 </chapter>
</xml>
```

Now I want to write an xslt which will make the text enclosed within  tag to bold.

**Desired output:**

```
This is a sample text. I want to **display this text in bold.** This is good.
```

I am writing xsl-fo output.
**XSLT**

```
<xml>
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="chapter">
     <xsl:for-each select="node()">
           <xsl:if test="current()[name() = 'P']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[name() = 'P']"
                mode="p" />
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'P']" mode="p">
    <xsl:if test="current()/node()[name() = 'L-1']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()/node()[name() = 'L-1']"
            mode="l1" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'L-1']" mode="l1">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
    </fo:block>
            <xsl:if test="current()/node()[name() = 'E']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()/node()[name() = 'E']"
            mode="e" />
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'E']" mode="e">
    <fo:block font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
</xml>
```

**Explaination:**
I have to achieve a recursive method to traverse through every node. And this traversal has to be dynamic. Because at any point of time I dont know what kind of xml I will get. On a high level, i know the nodes structure. I have the xsd which has all the nodes defined and the child nodes which can be present in the parent node. Hence my xslt runs in recursion to check which is the current node and based on that I need to apply styles to it.

Now with the above xslt, once 'E' tag is encountered, the text following E tag is coming twice.

**Current output:**
 This is a sample text. I want to display this text in bold. This is good.  **display this text in bold.**

Suggest me please.

Comment: Do you have a XSLT to transform your XML yet? If you do, post it here. You will just need to add one simple template to make the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a XSLT stylesheet that is transforming the text, and no template that already processes that specific node, you can add this template (matches all occurences of `E` with a `type` attribute containing `bold`) which will replace the match with `fo:block` containing a `font-weight="bold"` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="E[@type='bold']">
    <fo:block font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

If you have no XSLT template at all and the text above is all you want, then you can use this stylesheet which will generate a minimal XSL-FO file containing the transformation you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/XMLFormat"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="p1"> <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-name="p1"> 
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="E[@type='bold']">
        <fo:block font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi..I tried it.. It is getting bold. But the text after E tag is not getting displayed. Please help. I have added my xslt.

Answer (score 0):

As part of my XML I have something like this:

```
Only for testing... I want to be <nmb_list_bold>bold</nmb_list_bold> and other want to be <nmb_list_italic>italic</nmb_list_italic>
```

and wherever the text goes I have `<xsl:apply-templates/>`

and I have added some new templates that can match whatever you like, per instance:

```
<xsl:template match="nmb_list_bold">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nmb_list_italic">
    <span style="font-style:italic;">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```